# data structure with O(1) search time complexity in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, time-complexity, c++14

is there a data structure in c++ that has a search time complexity of O(1)? As in to check if an element is present in it or not, and if present, what its position or associated index/ key/value is

Comment: There's no way to have a O(1) time complexity for searching data.

Comment: Hash table, for example. Take a look at `std::unoredered_map`.

Comment: @Evg Even hash tables aren't actually O(1), approximately at best.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, sure. I hope OP knows that.

Comment: Be careful of the overhead constant.  For less than say 100,000 elements an unsorted std::vector may be faster.  You need to measure.

Comment: Arrays and vectors have O(1) time to lookup the item at a specified index; that’s about it.  Most other things are O(log N) at best.  (Hash table lookups can be O(1) for most cases but don’t guarantee it)

Comment: Linear search on a vector is O(1) because every vector has a max number of elements.  ;p

Comment: @RichardCritten I very much doubt a linear search through a vector of 100k elements (or even just 100 elements) would beat a lookup in a typical hash table of the same size, especially when you have bigger objects that aren't trivial to compare. If you said the O(log n) map could be faster than the O(1) unordered_map for those sizes, I'd agree with you.

Comment: @Dukeling Watch this "Modern C++: What You Need to Know - Herb Sutter" from about __46 mins__ into the presentation https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661 where inserting random values into a std::vector so that they are sorted, outperforms all other contains up to 500,000 elements (it's more but that is where they stopped testing).  Conclusion you need to measure and gut-feeling is not reliable.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's vector vs list, so not really applicable here. They briefly mention map, but that's still mainly doing insert / remove, rather than search and they don't mention unordered_map there at all. At 53:00 they literally say "for dictionary lookup, use map / unordered_map". I'm not going by gut-feeling - I have done plenty of measuring in my day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is C++11's `std::unordered_map`, with an average access time of O(1) and a worst case of O(n).

Comment: in which case does the access time end up being O(n)

Comment: im pretty sure it usually happens when there is a lot of collision. If the dataset elements are mostly unique, using an unordered map is makes sense, but that is rarely the case

Answer (score 4):

There are also the high-quality, open-source ["Swiss table" containers](https://abseil.io/blog/20180927-swisstables) in Google's Abseil library. At CppCon 2017, [there was a fun talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncHmEUmJZf4) that describes the implementation and goals of these containers.

In short, they are like the hash containers in the standard, but they usually provide better performance because they are more cache-friendly (at the expense of not maintaining reference stability, as noted in the comments).

Comment: upvoted because nobody should use unordered_ containers, they are just bad design...  but please make note in your answer that swiss containers do not offer reference stability.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl That is a big claim, you are going to need to substantiate it! (Perhaps not too much in comments, but do you have a link?)

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, there is a cppcon talk about flat hash map by Google guy. Long story short is that API mandated by the standard forces bad implementation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncHmEUmJZf4

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Fair enough, I'm aware of that. It just seemed your comment went a whole lot further than "there are a lot of cases where `unordered_map` is less than ideal". The pitfall of short comments on the internet, I suppose. Thanks for the link.